# Is the word "could" here in the past or present?

Tags: grammar

**[SOURCE](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/9640859/4/Holder)**

Context : A guy wakes up and a girl tells him that he slept with her during the night (*the girl is his friend*). He denies this and says:

> Since you've tempted me so much until now, I would've done everything *I could imagine* throughout the night, so there's no way you would be so energetic right now.

By *could*, does he mean  everything he could **(can)** imagine (while he's speaking) or everything he could imagine during the night ? I know that sometimes we use *could* like **can** and I'm not sure which one is the correct one here.

Comment: _Would have done_ places the action in an imagined past. _Could_ is thus called for as the preterit of _can._ We would never use the present tense here.

Comment: *Could* is always has the  past tense form. But sometimes it's used to refer to present tense moments: *Could you loan me a pen?* Frankly, your text is not written very well. Using *could have (imagined)* goes better here, because of *would have*.

Comment: Well it's not me the writer , it's from a novel that I was reading it's exactly how it was written, P. E. Dant answered my question therefore could in the text is about the past (He could imagine during the night) but I agree could have imagined is better (and more understandable for me as an english learner).

Answer (score 1):

In this context could doesn't refer to present tense.

> I would've done everything I could imagine throughout the night.

He is talking about assumption and he uses could as the past tense of can.